# How can I use Oracle Server local or online for academic practices with my classmates?

Tags: oracle, plsql, database-administration

I am learning to use Oracle from creating users, roles, tablespaces, etc. to using PL/SQL commands.

I would like to practice with my classmates by creating users for them to access from their computers at home.

I read that I need to set up a listener, but I don't know how to make the database accessible to them locally.

Do you know of any tutorial that can guide me through this process?

Alternatively, is there any online platform that allows me to use Oracle for this purpose? The idea is to practice creating users, roles, and permissions remotely.

I appreciate any suggestions.

I have read it in books, but i didn't find information available on this topic

Answer (score 3):

This is a very broad question, but I'll try to summarize. You have several options. Here are some of the simplest ones.

- For simple Oracle SQL practice, you can sign up for a free Oracle account and use the [Oracle Live SQL](https://livesql.oracle.com/) site. You cannot create users or manage privileges.
- You could also provision an [Oracle Autonomous Database](https://oracle.github.io/learning-library/data-management-library/database/db-quickstart/workshops/livelabs/?nav=open&lab=intro) in the cloud. You could provide access to this to your classmates. There is a an Always-Free tier, and there is also a limited trial that will eventually cost money.

There are several options you could install locally on your computer. It is possible (but difficult and not recommended) to share access to your computer with others.

- You can install [Oracle XE](https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/appdev/xe.html).
- You can also install and run Oracle locally using a [Docker container image](https://github.com/oracle/docker-images/blob/main/OracleDatabase/SingleInstance/README.md). It's not hard to find tutorials, [for instance this one](https://medium.com/geekculture/run-oracle-database-21c-in-docker-351049344d0c).